# Databinding selectedindex + 1

Tags: wpf, binding

I would like to bind a textbox to show the text of the item below the item that is selected.

Example:

Item 1 - Text = row numer one
Item 2 - Text = row number two
Item 3 - Text = row number three

I select item 2

output

Textbox 1 - Text = row number two (this is easily set up binding to selecteditem)
Textbox 2 - Text = row number three

I was thinking of a custom xpath of selectedindex + 1 but this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### first attempt failed -- see below

You need to implement an `IValueConverter` and set it to the `Converter` attribute of the binding.

Create a class that inherits from `IValueConverter`, and in the `Convert` method, you'll cast the `value` parameter to `ListBox` (because you'll be binding the `TextBox` to the `ListBox` itself and letting the converter turn that into something meaningful).

Then get a reference to the `ListBox`'s `SelectedIndex` property.

You want to return `listBox.Items[selectedIndex + 1]` from the method.

You can leave the `ConvertBack` method unimplemented.

You'll also have to handle the case where the last item in the `ListBox` is selected, because index + 1 will be out of bounds. Maybe you want to return the first item; maybe you want to return `null` or `string.Empty`.

#### update: custom ListBox

As requested, here is a sample that uses a custom ListBox with an additional [Dependency] property called "ItemAfterSelected."

First, the code for the derived control:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
     public class PlusOneListBox : ListBox
     {
          public PlusOneListBox()
          {
                SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single;
          }

          public object ItemAfterSelected
          {
                get { return GetValue(ItemAfterSelectedProperty); }
                set { SetValue(ItemAfterSelectedProperty, value); }
          }
          public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemAfterSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ItemAfterSelected", typeof (object), typeof (PlusOneListBox));

          protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
          {
                var newly_selected = e.AddedItems;
                if (newly_selected == null) ItemAfterSelected = null;
                else
                {
                     var last_index = Items.Count - 1;
                     var index = Items.IndexOf(newly_selected[0]);
                     ItemAfterSelected = index < last_index
                                                     ? Items[index + 1]
                                                     : null;
                }
                base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
          }
     }
}
```

Here is a sample window that shows how to use and bind to the control (you can drop this in to an app and run it to see it in action).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
          xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Padding="24">
     <StackPanel>
          <custom:PlusOneListBox x:Name="custom_listbox">
                <custom:PlusOneListBox.Items>
                     <System:String>one</System:String>
                     <System:String>two</System:String>
                     <System:String>three</System:String>
                     <System:String>four</System:String>
                     <System:String>five</System:String>
                     <System:String>six</System:String>
                </custom:PlusOneListBox.Items>
          </custom:PlusOneListBox>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8">
                <TextBlock Text="Selected: " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=custom_listbox}" />
          </StackPanel>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8">
                <TextBlock Text="Next: " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemAfterSelected, ElementName=custom_listbox}" />
          </StackPanel>
     </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? I curently have the following but I know that I'm not even close to what it should be...

public class IndexConverter : IValueConverter

  {    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)

      {

          
  listBox_Copy.SelectedIndex;
          return listBox_Copy[SelectedIndex + 1];

      }
 public object ConvertBack(object listBox_Copy, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture){}
      

  }

Comment: This solution won't work because the converter will only get called once when the ListBox is created. Because you're binding to the ListBox itself the Binding won't be getting any change notifications when the selection changes so won't try to update and call Convert again.

Comment: @John Ah, you are right, of course. At this point, I'd suggest creating a derived `ListBox` and just add a `DependencyProperty` like `ItemAfterSelected` which gets updated whenever the `SelectedItem` changes (override `OnSelectionChanged`).

Comment: Can you provide me with some example code, I've got no clue how to implement this..

Comment: @interetwjm I'll work up a quick sample this evening (GMT -5) and post the code in an update.

Comment: Hey, any chance of giving me an example? That would be great

Comment: @internetwjm Oooo! Sorry about that -- yes; forthcoming!

Comment: @internetwjm Updated with sample.